# I am using godaddy hosting. Browser Router is now loading the index.html into the browser. React-router-dom version(6.21.1)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My app. js file

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import { BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import About from "./About";
import Service from "./Service";
import Home from "./Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='/service/' element={<Service />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "navigate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [QSA, L]
 </IfModule>
```

I am create a new react app by npx create-react-app. Then install **react-router-dom** .
When i use **BrowserRouter** in my app.js after that is run the **npm run build** command. A build folder appear. Then i open index.html into my browser it shows nothing. i also open the file with live server by live-server extension in vs code. It shows a blank page.

Comment: You can't just open the HTML file in the browser, the app needs to be served to the browser in order for it to run correctly. Does it work when you use `npm start` in development builds and CRA serves it from `localhost:3000`? After building the app the built artifact/directory still needs to be served/hosted somewhere. Also, use `index` or `path="/"`, but not both.

Comment: yes it is working fine with npm start and it is also working fine with HashRouter. when i upload the build into the server and added .htaccess file to the server then also not working

Comment: What is the server or hosting service? Can you [edit] to add these details and the associated settings and/or configurations?

Comment: i am using godaddy hosting. Apache server is used by godaddy to host my file

Comment: Can you share the .htaccess file?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing